# .NET scales image when drawing to graphics

Tags: c#, .net, bitmap, png

I want to make a programm which merges png images into one png. 
All the images are 78px height, 120px width, so I created a bitmap 1200x78 (I need to merge 10 images)
It merges, but every image in the result png is scaled approximately x2. Why?

Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Security;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1;
        Bitmap bitmap;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
            openFileDialog1.Multiselect = true;
            openFileDialog1.Filter =
        "Images (*.PNG;*.JPG;*.GIF)|*.PNG;*.JPG;*.GIF|" +
        "All files (*.*)|*.*";
            openFileDialog1.Title = "Select images to merge";

            bitmap = new Bitmap(1200, 78);
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DialogResult dr = this.openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();

            if (dr == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            {
                // Read the files
                int shift = 0;
                foreach (String file in openFileDialog1.FileNames)
                {
                    // Create a PictureBox.
                    try
                    {
                        PictureBox pb = new PictureBox();
                        Image loadedImage = Image.FromFile(file);
                        pb.Height = loadedImage.Height;
                        pb.Width = loadedImage.Width;
                        pb.Image = loadedImage;
                        flowLayoutPanel2.Controls.Add(pb);

                        paintToBitmap(loadedImage, shift);

                        shift += loadedImage.Width;
                    }
                    catch (SecurityException ex)
                    {
                        //  The user lacks appropriate permissions to read files, discover paths, etc.
                        MessageBox.Show("Security error\n\n" +
                           "Error message: " + ex.Message + "\n\n" +
                            "Details (send to Support):\n\n" + ex.StackTrace
                        );
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        // Could not load the image - probably related to Windows file system permissions.
                        MessageBox.Show("!!!");
                    }
                }


                saveImage();
            }
        }

        private void paintToBitmap(Image image, int shift)
        {           
            Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap);
            graphics.DrawImage(image, new Point(shift, 0));
        }

        private void saveImage()
        {
            bitmap.Save("d:\\result.png", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
        }

        private void flowLayoutPanel2_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I ran your code and it seems to work fine. Could you attach one of your input images? I'd guess that this is an issue with your images in respect to dpi or alike.

Comment: http://files.moonmana.com/forums/m1.png
http://files.moonmana.com/forums/m2.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try update your code to this

```
graphics.DrawImage(image, new Rectangle(shift, 0,120,78));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, rectangle helped, but the third parameter is width so it should be just 120, without shift.
graphics.DrawImage(image, new Rectangle(shift, 0,120,78));

Answer (score 1):

It seems that it try to adapt the picture to the size of your "pink dog :P" image. When you fill the image with a background it result in different way. see this:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3eVEu.png]
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DaygF.png]
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xwEve.png]

so, the problem seems to be in the invisible background of your picture.

Comment: How do you know your example works if you're using rectangles filled with one color? :)
You're drawing a rectangle at 0,0 it drawed resized from 120 to 240, than you're drawing your next rectangle at 120, so it overlaps a part of the first resized rectangle and so on ;)